# Autodesk Platform Services: How to display tooltip of sensor data using "Handling Sprite Events"?

Tags: tooltip, autodesk-forge

Autodesk Platform Services:How to display sensor data using Handling Sprite Events

I'm working on creating an IoT data visualization viewer using the Data Visualization feature of Autodesk Platform Services(formerly Forge), which is featured below.
[Developer's Guide](https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/dataviz/v1/developers_guide/examples/sprites/handling_sprite_events/)
[Live demo](https://aps-iot-extensions-demo.autodesk.io/)
[Source code](https://github.com/autodesk-platform-services/aps-iot-extensions-demo)

I'd like to create a tooltip function to display detailed sensor data by clicking on the sensor icon, as shown in the Developer's Guide and the following image.
However, this functionality is not provided in the prepared source code.
(There is a function in SensorSpritesExtension.js for handling similar click events.)

[image]

**From the above, there are two points I would like to know.
**

1. Is there a sample source code or demo available that provides a mouse click event process that displays IoT sensor data like the image?
2. If 1. is not available, is there any API reference, Developer's Guide, or technical blog that we can refer to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hover tooltips shown in the GIFs were implemented in an older code sample (https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge-dataviz-iot-reference-app), however this sample was difficult to reuse, which is why we built a new one (https://github.com/autodesk-platform-services/aps-iot-extensions-demo). In the new sample, the charts for individual sensors are displayed in a custom UI panel when you click on their icons. Btw. to implement this behavior, the new sample is also making use of the `Autodesk.DataVisualization.Core.MOUSE_CLICK` event: https://github.com/autodesk-platform-services/aps-iot-extensions-demo/blob/464ce80637b8e258c1499a4569f53ab1aeb65203/public/extensions/SensorSpritesExtension.js#LL26C38-L26C81.